# onClick create or remove objects using XML elements

Tags: android, xml

So I currently have some code that will populate a page with a number of TextViews and Buttons onCreate, and these are for selecting dates and times. I want to have a button that will add shifts which would bring up another two copies of the buttons and the TextViews as well.
So I was just wondering how I would go about doing this. 
I know how to set up OnClickListeners with no issues, I'm just unsure what I have to do to create new objects that would use the XML layout properties I have already created in my main.xml file, when the button is clicked.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is create everything you need in main.xml initially, but hide the stuff you aren't going to be displaying right away. Then in your OnClickListener, you can show/hide whatever it is you want using the [setVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) method. So your xml would look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
  <!-----Stuff you need initially ---->
  <Button ...>
  <TextVeiw ...>
  <!----Stuff you'll need eventually---->
  <Button android:visibility="invisible" ...>
  <TextView android:visibility="invisible" ...>
</LinearLayout>
```

The visibility attribute actually has three values it can take on: visibile, invisible, and gone. Which one you pick will depend on your implementation needs. For more information see [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility).

Comment: I guess that would work, but then I would end up with an XML file that would have to have a ridiculous amount of invisible elements since they require multiple elements for each shift.
I'm thinking dynamically adding them would work, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this properly.
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this [tutorial](http://www.aslingandastone.com/2010/dynamically-changing-android-views/)? It seems to deal with dynamically adding and removing layout elements.

Comment: That would also work but I'd have to set up multiple xml files for each separate group of buttons. I'm quite unsure of what will solve my issue still.

Comment: couldn't you just create one compound UI component and add that however many times you need it?  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Comment: That sounds right, but getting my head around implementing it is confusing me a little. Could you provide an example for me?
Let's say I was using the following XML code:
<Button android:id="@+id/pickTimeEnd"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/timeDisplayEnd"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blank" android:text="End Time" />

Comment: <TextView android:id="@+id/shiftText" android:layout_width="wrap_content" style="@style/MyTextView"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"android:layout_below="@+id/pickTimeEnd" android:text="Shift Length:" />

Sorry about that, but this seems the easiest way to make it readable.

Comment: There are examples of compound controlls in the API Examples. As stated on the page I gave you: "In the API Demos project that comes with the SDK, there are two List examples — Example 4 and Example 6 under Views/Lists demonstrate a SpeechView which extends LinearLayout to make a component for displaying Speech quotes. The corresponding classes in the sample code are List4.java and List6.java."